# PHP Script Time-Out

Tags: php, wordpress, csv

On my WordPress 3.9.2 Hosted on Rackspace Cloud. I made a application to upload CSV files to the database. This CSV file uploading and updating database times-out because it passes 30 Seconds and the connection get's cut off. I was chatting with the Support Team, they direct me to this [WEBSITE](http://www.cloudsitesrock.com/?ac=post&id=9&uid=1&p=6&cat=0&m=0&y=0) I have no idea how to use it on my script. Below is the script am currently using.

```
<?php
/* After file is uploaded to the Server */
    $fp = fopen($location, 'r');
    $datas = array();
    $fgetcsv = fgetcsv($fp);
    while ( ($data = fgetcsv($fp) ) !== FALSE ){
   /* Loop and insert into database */
}
?>
```

Comment: You called `fgetcsv($fp)` twice

Comment: Why cant you increase the time limit to lets say 120 seconds `set_time_limit(120);` ?

Comment: @Hanky 웃 Panky According to Rackspace Support,  time limit won't work because they are using Load Balancer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/* After file is uploaded to the Server */
    $fp = fopen($location, 'r');
    $data = array();
    while ( ($data = fgetcsv($fp) ) !== FALSE ){
     sleep(1);
     echo ".";
     flush();
     /* Loop and insert into database */
}
?>
```

Try this out. This will work !

Comment: Thanks for the help. After applying your code, the browser times-out now and not the script.

Comment: Try this in Mozilla Firefox:

Open Firefox, and in the address bar, type "about:config" (without quotes). From there, scroll down to the Network.http.keep-alive and make sure that is set to "true". If it is not, double click it, and it will go from false to true. Now, go one below that to network.http.keep-alive.timeout -- and change that number by double clicking it. if you put in, say, 5000 there, you should be good. let us know if this helps at all